# HOUCKS UP A LUGI

Tags: meaning-in-context

> *Daisy Domergue looks over the letter with interest…
>
>   THEN…
>
>   HOUCKS UP A LUGI
>
>   and SPITS it on the letter with a BIG SPLAT.*

Source: https://indiegroundfilms.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/1390849759320.pdf Page 16 of PDF, numbered page 14.

This is a quote from the script from the movie The Hateful Eight by Quentin Tarantino. What does "houcks up a lugi" mean? My GOOGLE research failed. In the scene Daisy just spat on the letter.

Comment: I've made a few edits to your formatting to make the question more closely resemble the script. I can't tell you whether this is a genuine first draft or not but I can tell you that the all caps and other odd formatting is actually script standard. Major actions and sounds are often made to stand out by writing them in all caps lettering. This makes them more obvious when reading through the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mostly a spelling issue.

The phrase is normally spelled "[Hock a loogie](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hock%20a%20loogie)"... and it has an Urban Dictionary article:

> To cough up and spit out a large glob of flem usually resulting in a loud a cough and throat clearing noise.

Note that we generally spell "flem" - phlegm...

Essentially, "hocking up a loogie" is the act of clearing one's throat and then spitting out a blob of phlegm.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Is there any reason why to use HOUCKS UP A LUGI instead of standard "hocks up a loogie". Is it more "urbanier"?

Comment: Is that a direct quote from the script? The reality is, neither "hocks" nor "loogie" are "real" words... so spelling variations exist. Most scripts aren't "official" scripts, anyway... they're created by third parties to look like a script. There are a lot of spelling errors in your first paragraph. If that's a direct quote, looks like whoever created the "script" doesn't really know how to spell.

Comment: @bart-leby It's spelled the way that a poorly educated person might have written it (e.g. phonetically spelled the word).

Comment: @phyrfox why would someone write the script as if a poorly educated person wrote it?

Comment: @Catija I just realized what I said. Either English is not the script writer's first language, or they are in the lower 50% of America's educated. After the answer was edited, it's clear that the script writer does not command the English language: "Coffy's ready", "removes his pistol from it's holster and Fires", and so on.

Comment: @phyrfox can you note which pages you're talking about?

Comment: Pages 121 and 122, for example, but there's plenty more if you take a look. "mam" instead of "ma'am", lowercase "i" instead of "I", and so on.

Comment: @phyrfox From looking at the script, the **dialogue** is written *intentionally* in a dialect appropriate for the characters... likely to help the actors feel in character and get the accentuation and feel. The actions are written in normal modern English with a few slip-ups here and there. Even educated people occasionally make errors with "its" and "it's" :D

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the spelling with which I am am familiar is

> to hock up a loogie

Here is a definition from urban dictionary

> [hock a loogie](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hock%20a%20loogie)
>   To cough up and spit out a large glob of flem usually resulting in a loud a cough and throat clearing noise.

Here is a [tutorial](https://vimeo.com/96450396).

Comment: OMG really a tutorial!

Comment: Are you criticizing me, or are you shocked? OP was reading a script, so I thought that a video might make it very clear.

Comment: I took it as being surprised such a thing existed. We're a little chattier here than some other SEs :) I think it's a great addition to an answer so you get a +1 from me.

Comment: @ColleenV Yeah, I thought so too. The `!` threw me off. I was also surprised. It's kinda gross, but educational I suppose. Haha. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Both [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hock%20a%20loogie)
and the script in question misspell the first word.
The standard spelling is *hawk*:

> **hawk<sup>3</sup>** – verb 1
>   
>   Clear the throat noisily:
>    
>   *‘he* hawked *and spat into the flames’*
>   
>   1.1.   [with object] (*hawk* something up) Bring phlegm up from the throat.
>   
>   *‘Well most people can* hawk *it up and spit it out of their mouth… but I cannot do that.’*
>   
>   [– OxfordDictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hawk#hawk-3__2)

Incidentally, the pronunciation familiar to me (west coast USA)
is like "huck," which is slang for *throw.*

The second word is nonstandard English and typically spelled *loogie*:

> **loogie** – noun
>   
>   1.   (US, slang) A thick quantity of sputum, usually containing phlegm.
>   
>   2.   (US, slang) Any thick, disgusting liquid.
>   
>   [– Wikitionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loogie#Noun)

Comment: [Etymology online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hawk) lists it as an [imitative](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/onomatopoeic) so it's not surprising that there are variations in the spelling.